# обработчик события

Tags: javascript

Как можно не убрать, а остановить обработчик события `addEventListener`
если допустим есть js код:

```
var count = 0;
el.addEventListener('click', function but(){        
    console.log(count);
    if (count >10) removeEventListener('click',but);
    count++;
}, false)
```

получится что при 11м клике ивент не будет иметь места быть.
А если этот самый `count` будет где-нибудь сбрасываться, то выходит это же событие уже не будет работать. Может нужно `false` возвращать или я чего то не до понимаю? Хотелось бы что бы 4я строка не удаляла ивент, а именно не давала функции ивента срабатывать, что в дальнейшем позволило бы пользоваться ней снова. 
Заранее извиняюсь за абстракцию

Comment: ну так и проверяйте в самом начале метода условие, и если оно подходящее делайте `return`

Comment: а разве не будет ошибки undefined на count?

Comment: А то что у вас этот count всегда == 1 и условие никогда не выполнится это так и задумано? Это к вам вопрос вообще-то, не будет ли ошибки undefined

Comment: пардон, исправил

Comment: для текущего кода - не будет :)

Comment: А если условие будет зависить напрямую от переменных обьявленных в функции?

Comment: например? если переменные объявлены _внутри_ функции, их состояние не сохраняется между вызовами

Comment: хм, действительно условия нужно ставить в начало метода. Но разве внутри функции локальные переменные влияют на очередность выполнения условия